# Replacing '%20' from the downloaded excel file

Tags: php, excel, tableexportjs

I have extracted an excel file from html table by using the library tableExport. But the downloaded file has '%20' in places of spaces which make it to an unreadable format.

The downloaded file data is the format as below:

```
Date%20of%20Notification
```

And I have to extract the excel file in the same excel filename which I have displayed as the html table. I have used following code for this:

XLS

This code extracts the html table as xls. Is there anyway to download it in the xlsx format using tableExport library?

Comment: You probably need https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php but since you didn't include any code it's hard to help you

Answer (score 0):

Not familiar with Excel or tableExportLibrary - but the %20 issue can be solved using https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rawurldecode.php .

Comment: I think it's the content, not the file name/link.

Comment: Hi Andreas, title or content, you normally have a variable holding a string value. From that point, PHP doesn't know/care wether the text is title or content. 

IMHO, html_entity-decode() is incorrect, as this converts ampersand codes ( &quot; , &lt; , ... ), and not percent codes ( %20, ... ), to HTML